# Doctrine/Mongodb regex

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a large MongoDB and want to get all records where 'fullname' field must meets these requirements

Must contain 'ac' or 'a/c' or 'abc'
Must not contain 'queen'

```
$data = $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:Data')
            ->field('fullname')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/(ab?/?c$)/i'))
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->immortal(true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Right now I'm using it like above, and it works, and have this to exclude 'queen'.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!stristr($row['fullname']), 'queen')) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But I would like Mongo to handle it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mongo support negative lookahead then you may use this,

```
^(?!.*queen).*a[b\/]?c
```

You may use the above regex for condition checking which finds a match only if the string won't conatin `queen` substring and the string must contain the substring `ab` or `abc` or `a/c`

Comment: Mongo regexes are "pcre". Or technically from boost I believe. So yes.